# How can a plot a map with folium and place a bar graph next to the map in python?

Tags: python, folium

I have a dataframe and I have been creating a interactive bar graph with widgets to show different characteristics of the dataframe and I am only missing to show the location with the latitud and longitud in the dataframe but i dont know how to show those two with a single visualization i know hot to plot the markers with the latitud and longitud in a separate visulization but how can I plot them side to side?

Comment: I believe you can use subplot and have two plots in the widget. One with the bar graph and the other with the markers.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I was able to plot the graph and the map below the graph but not side to side because by using subplot another graph was creating which makes me think i cant treat the map as a subplot, any other ideas for making it side to side?

Answer (score 1):

a bit old, but we now have a solution for this using `ipywidgets`

```
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import folium
from IPython.display import display

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
# do your figure work here

mp = folium.Map()
# do your folium map work here

# save the image to a file handler in memory
tmpfile = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(tmpfile, format='png')

# close the figure to avoid this being re-rendered automatically by jupyter
plt.close()

# display the image and map converting them to widgets
display(widget.HBox([
     widget.Image(value=tmpfile.getvalue(), format='png', width='50%'), 
     widget.HTML(value=mp._repr_html_(), layout=widget.Layout(width='50%', height='97%', margin='3% 0 0 0'))
]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your plotted graphs to images and then:

```
import os
from folium.plugins import FloatImage

img = ('your_path_to_image')

f_map = folium.Map ([# lat long from df])

image = (img, bottom = 40,left =65).add_to(f_map)

f_map.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but when I run this code it shows me the following error:
 image = (img, bottom = 40,left =65).add_to(plot_locations_map)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  

***If I take the bottom and left part out*** I get the following error: 

---> 61     image = (img).add_to(f_map)
     62     display(f_map)
     63 

***AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_to'***

I’m thinking that maybe I’m no saving the image right, what am I suppose to write in the part of image = (“your_path_to_image") ????